# why is iloc performance different for identical data frames

Tags: python, pandas

In certain cases I see very different performance doing iloc on two identical dataframes.  The only difference being one dataframe having been created by concating several smaller dataframes.  This seems to only happen in a MultiIndex dataframe when the two indexes are of near the same size, and a relatively small portion of the entire dataframe is being selected.  See code sample.

Why is this happening, and is there a way I can adjust the concated data frame to always match the performance of the non-concated dataframe?

```
    tests = [
       (1000, 1000, 10),   
       (1000, 100,  10),     
       (100,  1000, 10),   
       (1000, 1000, 10),   
       (1000, 2000, 10),
       (1000, 1000, 1 ),
        ]

    for test in tests:
        print(test)
        size1, size2, selfactor = test

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(size1), np.arange(size2)], names=['A','B']))

        size1 = int(size1 / 10)
        df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(size1) + i * size1, np.arange(size2)], names=['A','B'])) for i in range(10)])

        pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1,df2)

        sel = np.arange(int(len(df1) / selfactor))

        for df in [df1,df2]:
            start = perf_counter()
            subset = df.iloc[sel]
            end = perf_counter()
            time = (end - start)*(1000)
            print(str(time))
        print()
```

Here is the output on my machine

```
(1000, 1000, 10)
3.601001928661345
5.113583139675888

(1000, 100, 10)
2.294054769875764
2.2780146721983474

(100, 1000, 10)
2.3068868480180527
2.2770522663373427

(1000, 1000, 10)
3.228230058629933
5.005472881327577

(1000, 2000, 10)
4.944520510150596
8.613211651013586

(1000, 1000, 1)
64.08596465789174
66.93789402500272
```

Comment: Do you really need to create an example with tens of millions of rows? My laptop is heating up, thanks for that

Comment: If you apply `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` to both dataframes, results become aligned. My hunch is that the first one pandas notices (and stores internally somewhere?) some meta noting that indices are unique, while in the second case after concat it hasn't noted this as such.

Comment: This didn't effect the performance, but if you use `pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal()` it will show that the first dataframe is using `Int64Index` on level 0 & the second is using `Float64Index` on level 0.

Comment: @jpp I agree, I was able to get the performance back by setting `df2.index = df1.index` something is screwy with the concatenated index.

Comment: sorry for the cpu burn.  In playing with the size of the sample I noticed the relative size of the parts of the multiindex makes a big difference in the relative speed of the iloc.  See updated example (with smaller sizes)

Comment: @AaronN.Brock sorry issue with the test, fixed now. Needed a cast to an int.